# spark-shell cannot parse Scala lines that start with dot / period

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Whenever I find some Scala / Spark code online, I want to directly paste it into spark-shell to try it out. (I am using spark-shell with Spark 1.6 on both CentOS and Mac OS.)

Generally, this approach works well, but I always have problems when lines start with a dot / period (indicating a continuing method call). If I move the dot to the previous line, it works.

Example: Here is some code I found online:

```
val paramMap = ParamMap(lr.maxIter -> 20)
  .put(lr.maxIter, 30) 
  .put(lr.regParam -> 0.1, lr.threshold -> 0.55)
```

So when I paste this directly into spark-shell, I see this error:

```
scala> val paramMap = ParamMap(lr.maxIter -> 20)
paramMap: org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamMap = 
{
    logreg_d63b85553548-maxIter: 20
}

scala>   .put(lr.maxIter, 30) 
<console>:1: error: illegal start of definition
         .put(lr.maxIter, 30) 
         ^

scala>   .put(lr.regParam -> 0.1, lr.threshold -> 0.55)
<console>:1: error: illegal start of definition
         .put(lr.regParam -> 0.1, lr.threshold -> 0.55)
         ^
```

However, when I instead move the dot to the previous line, everything is ok.

```
scala> val paramMap = ParamMap(lr.maxIter -> 20).
     | put(lr.maxIter, 30).
     | put(lr.regParam -> 0.1, lr.threshold -> 0.55)
paramMap: org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamMap = 
{
    logreg_d63b85553548-maxIter: 30,
    logreg_d63b85553548-regParam: 0.1,
    logreg_d63b85553548-threshold: 0.55
}
```

Is there a way to configure spark-shell so that it will accept lines that start with a dot (or equivalently, so that it will continue lines even if they don't end in a dot)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There must be no leading whitespace.

```
scala> "3"
res0: String = 3

scala> .toInt
res1: Int = 3

scala> "3"
res2: String = 3

scala>   .toInt
<console>:1: error: illegal start of definition
  .toInt
  ^
```

PS: Maybe it should ignore whitespace when a dot is detected. A JIRA was added on that concern [here](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9749).

Comment: ps) maybe it should ignore leading whitespace when detecting dot-selection.

Answer (score 4):

Use [:paste](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-enter-paste-multiline-commands-statements-into-scala-repl) command:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

if (true)
  print("that was true")
else
  print("false")

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

that was true
```

Comment: That's really inconvenient to type ":paste" whenever you want to paste in code.

Answer (score 3):

you can also wrap your expression with curly braces

```
val paramMap = { ParamMap(lr.maxIter -> 20)
  .put(lr.maxIter, 30) 
  .put(lr.regParam -> 0.1, lr.threshold -> 0.55)
}
```

This is because: *The REPL is “greedy” and consumes the first full statement you type in, so attempting to paste blocks of code into it can fail*

for more details see: http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-repl-how-to-paste-load-blocks-of-source-code

There is also nice feature `:paste -raw`

See http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/repl/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

The Spark shell has a built-in mechanism to allow for pasting in multiple line Spark Scala code or writing line-by-line Spark Scala code: by wrapping your code in parenthesis `()`. Moving your dots to the end of the line is not needed.

In your example start off with `val paramMap = (`. From here you can write each line by hand or paste in your multi-line linear regression hyperparameter code. Then add one more parenthesis `)` after your code is finished to encapsulate it. When using this method don't use tab for indentation but use two spaces instead.

Full code example:

```
scala> val paramMap = (ParamMap(lr.maxIter -> 20)
 |   .put(lr.maxIter, 30)
 |   .put(lr.regParam -> 0.1, lr.threshold -> 0.55)
 | )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also put the periods on the line before, then it works fine.  Although this may break style conventions

```
val paramMap = ParamMap(lr.maxIter -> 20).
  put(lr.maxIter, 30).
  put(lr.regParam -> 0.1, lr.threshold -> 0.55)
```